# How to prevent tabulator input to close when clicking elsewhere

Tags: tabulator

I have a custom datepicker calendar I want to show for editing dates in tabulator. I have managed to open the calendar when the row cell is click by providing a custom editor.

The problem is that as soon as I click on my calendar, (what I think happens) is that Tabulator´s "As a fallback Tabulator will cancel the edit if an editor is blured and the event has not been correctly handled." behavior triggers before I can process the click on my calendar and update the cell value.

Is there a way to allow the user to click on the calendar without making tabulator cancel the edit?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which custom date picker you are using but here is a working example using [flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr):

```js
let initialTableData = [{
    eventName: "Christmas party",
    eventDate: "12-25-2021"
  },
  {
    eventName: "New Years party",
    eventDate: "12-31-2021"
  }
]

function dateEditor(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
  let editor = document.createElement("input")
  editor.value = cell.getValue()

  let datepicker = flatpickr(editor, {
    dateFormat: "m-d-Y",
    onChange: setDate,
    onClose: setDate
  })

  function setDate(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    success(dateStr)
    instance.destroy()
  }

  onRendered(() => {
    editor.focus()
  })

  return editor
}

let eventTable = new Tabulator("#eventTable", {
  data: initialTableData,
  columns: [{
      title: "Event",
      field: "eventName",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      title: "Event Date",
      field: "eventDate",
      editor: dateEditor
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.0.7/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.0.7/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="eventTable"></div>
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/izmirli/pen/WNZjYdK)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. I was able to figure out why it was not working.